# Merging multiple sql update statements(Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I'm not very good at sql and I've tried a few things. What would be the best way to combine these 5 update statements into a single statement considering **performance** of the code? Would be a great help. Thank you so much!

Code:

```
----------------1

Update main_table
set  a = (case
..some code..  end)
where condition_2;

----------------2

Update main_table
set  b = (case
..some code.. end)
where condition_2

----------------3

Update main_table
set  c = (select x from sec_table where conditon_1)
where condition_2

----------------4

Update main_table
set  d = (select y from sec_table where conditon_1)
where condition_2

----------------5

Update main_table
set  e = (select z from sec_table where conditon_1)
where condition_2
```

Comment: I have already tried this but I'm looking for better performance:    
UPDATE main_table
SET 
 a = (CASE
                      some code
                              END),
 b = (CASE
                    some code
                 END),
    c =
  (SELECT x
   FROM sec_table
   WHERE condition_2),
    
    d =
  (SELECT y
   FROM sec_table
   WHERE condition_2),
   
   e =
  (SELECT z
   FROM sec_table
   WHERE condition_2)
WHERE condition_1;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can write this as:

```
update main_table
    set a = (case ..some code.. end), 
        b = (case ..some code.. end), 
        (c, d, e) = (select x, y, z from sec_table where conditon_1)
where condition_2
```

Comment: I have tried this but ---- (c, d, e) = (select x, y, z from sec_table where conditon_1)---- this part of code gave me some unexpected results.

Comment: I believe I'm doing something wrong with the condition in where clause

Answer (score 2):

You can combine your update queries  and use only one query like this :

```
UPDATE main_table
   SET a = (case ..some code.. end) ,
       b = (case ..some code.. end) ... /*the rest of your sets*/
   where /*add your conditions*/
```

Answer (score 0):

you can perform that on only one update statement. Depending on the subquery you're making on that sec_table you might even tune a little more.

```
update main_table set a= (case ..some code.. end), 
                      b= (case ..some code.. end), 
                      c= (select x from sec_table where conditon_1),      
                      d= (select y from sec_table where conditon_1),
                      e= (select z from sec_table where conditon_1) 
where condition_2
```